# NullPointerException during IR Conversion with android-gradle-plugin 3.6.0

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-r8

Release build throws (when using `gradle installRelease`) :

```
NullPointerException during IR Conversion
```

After upgrading com.android.tools.build:gradle from 3.5.3 to 3.6.0.
Error happens when transforming jetified lib from ~/.gradle/caches/.../jetified-lib.jar

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

NullPointerException during IR Conversion
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.y0.a(:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O.a(:51)
    ... 97 more
```

Anyone knows how to solve the issue ?

EDIT :

Looking at https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin adding this to gradle.properties

```
android.useNewApkCreator=false
```

does not help...

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150330356

Comment: Also happens with bundleRelease but not bundleDebug or installdebug

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: check my answer bellow, best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is available in Google r8 repo. Until Google releases AGP 3.6.2 or greater you have to override r8 AGP dependency in your gradle build file with latest r8 release :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.Y.Z'
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.6.78' // MUST BE AFTER AGP 
    }
}
```

or downgrade to AGP 3.5.x

Answer (score 0):

You should check your full error log, it might give you an idea what's causing it.

It might not be completely related to your issue but I've had the same error after upgrade and it was caused by the Heap analytics plugin.

```
Error: /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files
2.1/f09a86d8ecd2a3b98534de60989936ee/jetified-heap-android-client-1.1.1-runtime.jar:com/heapanalytics/android/internal/CommonProtos$DeviceInfo.class
,java.lang.Objectcom.heapanalytics.android.internal.CommonProtos$DeviceInfo
.dynamicMethod(com.google.protobuf
.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)

NullPointerException during IR Conversion
```

Comment: please check the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150330356